# converting xml DOMDocument to string

Tags: php, xml, ajax

HI i am using ajax for a web site which displays courses available,  i am having a problem where i am reading xml(which has courses details) getting node value(course name) comparing to my input(inout course name) if it is equal i am displaying the text(course description).
 now i am  tracing it getting to correct course name(in xml file) but while comparing it to input course name its not at all comparing so.at one point i loaded the xml file and echo it:

```
$doc->load('data/ICT.xml'); 
echo"$doc";
```

It gives me an error

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class DOMDocument could not be converted to string in /home/students/....../www/htdocs/client/unit_details.php on line 23

so what i understood from this is that xml dom object should be converted to string so that i can get required data and use it, is it true? if so can some one tell me how to do so please(like any functions etc) thanks in advance :-)

Comment: [`DOMDocument`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) implements the DOM API - access nodes via things like `getElementById(), getElementsByClassName()`, etc, and use `saveXML()` to write out a string.

Answer (score 43):

The `DOMDocument` object can't be used as a string.

Here is how you would display the `DOMDocument` object as an XML string:

```
echo $doc->saveXML();
```

Answer (score 17):

`DOMDocument` has a method [`SaveHTML()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php), it's designed to do exactly what you need.

You may display whole document by:

```
$doc->saveHTML();
```

Or just certain node:

```
$doc->saveHTML( $bodyNode);
```

[`DOMDocument`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) also provides few options how to enhance how the XML is print, such as:

- [`preserveWhiteSpaces`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php#domdocument.props.preservewhitespace)
- [`formatOutput`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php#domdocument.props.formatoutput)
- [`encoding`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php#domdocument.props.encoding)
- ...

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
$xml = $doc->saveXML($doc->documentElement);
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use Type casting

```
$doc->load('data/ICT.xml'); 
$doc2=(string)$doc;
echo $doc2;
```

Or You can use the PHP function

```
strval();
```

This function returns the string values of the parameter passed to it.

Comment: You should better read the question before answering it: *"Catchable fatal error: Object of class DOMDocument could not be converted to string in /home/students/....../www/htdocs/client/unit_details.php on line 23"*